# How is ReLU used in neural networks if it doesn't squish the weighted sum into the interval of (0, 1)?

Tags: neural-networks, activation-function, relu

So as far as I understand from watching 3Blue1Brown's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aircAruvnKk) on neural networks, all neurons operate on numbers ranging from 0 to 1. Since a weighted sum goes larger than that, a sigmoid function is used to squish it back into that interval. How does a ReLU work then if it doesn't force numbers into that interval? Or is it used in networks operating in numbers that can be greater than 1?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What makes you think that neurons only operate on values between zero and one? (I haven’t seen 3B1B’s video in a long time, so it might be that his entire discussion concerned sigmoid activation functions, which do squash into $(0,1)$.)